# vertx how to get post handler work more effectively

Tags: vert.x

i am new to vertx, and trying to do a test to migrate some legacy code to vertx, to promote the qps performance. but i encountered trouble when migrate the post method.

i try to add some code like below, and i can get form attribute from request and get handler works

```
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create(false));

.handler(routingContext -> {
         HttpServerRequest request = routingContext.request();
         request.setExpectMultipart(true);
         request.endHandler(end -> {
           // request.params().addAll(request.formAttributes());
           routingContext.next();
         });
})
```

but i found the qps drop down rapidly, the handler do mysql transaction inside.

```
wrk -t 4 -c 5000 -d 100s -T 30s --latency --script=post.lua http://xxx:8080/api/test-post
Running 2m test @ http://xxx:8080/api/test-post
  4 threads and 5000 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    62.05ms   24.48ms 379.37ms   75.58%
    Req/Sec     4.11k     2.27k   14.34k    56.06%
  Latency Distribution
     50%   63.10ms
     75%   74.89ms
     90%   89.70ms
     99%  127.75ms
  1630551 requests in 1.67m, 181.94MB read
  Socket errors: connect 3983, read 0, write 0, timeout 0
  Non-2xx or 3xx responses: 1630551
Requests/sec:  16289.62
Transfer/sec:      1.82MB

wrk -t 4 -c 5000 -d 100s -T 30s --latency --script=post.lua http://xxx:8080/api/test-post
4 threads and 5000 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     2.49s   451.83ms   5.09s    92.64%
    Req/Sec   157.46    105.25   514.00     62.56%
  Latency Distribution
     50%    2.38s
     75%    2.58s
     90%    2.82s
     99%    4.93s
  39585 requests in 1.67m, 2.68MB read
  Socket errors: connect 3983, read 0, write 0, timeout 0
Requests/sec:    395.60
Transfer/sec:     27.43KB
```

i use vertx 4
4.0.0-milestone4

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to compare from your question. But this probably has nothing to do with reading form fields.

Comment: it is my fault, seems that mysql transaction cause the performance issue